# Converting each cell value of raster into floating-point representation using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-conversion, qgis-2.18, floating-point

I have several bands of raster from the Landsat8 satellite, and I need to convert them into a floating-point representation. In ArcMap this is done through:

Spatial Analyst Toolbox -> Math -> Trigonometric -> Float.

How do I accomplish this in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this by utilizing the GdalTools plugin. 
**GDAL -> GDAL Conversion -> Translate (convert format)**. 
I chose the output raster to have the data type float32, and received a GeoTIFF with proper float data type.